# calculate function return type for a given input type

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I would like to calculate the return type for a given function given a parameter type.
So for e.g. a function with signature `a -> a` and a parameter type `Bool`, I would like to get the return type `Bool`.
Now, this works:

```hs
-- $ ghci -XScopedTypeVariables
> import Test.QuickCheck
> import Data.Typeable
> fn = id
> param :: Bool <- generate arbitrary
> typeOf $ fn param
Bool
```

However, having to instantiate the parameter type then execute the function feels a bit overkill, if the goal is just to obtain its return type.

I imagine that, knowing the param type `Bool`, we would know the type variable `a` would also become `Bool`, and that therefore we can substitute this in the return type `a` as well, to obtain return type `Bool`.

Is there a way to dynamically obtain such a function return type without having to resort to executing the function?

Comment: What about `:t fn param`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem while that works in ghci, I would like to be able to get this info as part of a wider program. :/

Comment: But Haskell is statically typed, hence there is no reason to do that in the program. At the time of compilation, *all* types are known. In fact one can do *full* type erasure.

Comment: Can you do this exercise for me: imagine that you already have the way to do what you're asking for. **First**, can you post how it would look to the consumer? Like, would it be a function? If so, what would be its type signature? Feel free to imagine things you don't know into existence. **Second**, imagine how you would use it. Just post some pseudo-ish-Haskell code that gives an example of what you're going to ultimately do with this thing. If you do that, people here will be able to give you a much better answer.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin as you said `Type` isn't something you can have values of at run-time (unlike in say Idris), while I know `Data.Typeable.typeOf` is allergic to polymorphic types such as `id`'s `a -> a`, so `TypeRep` is out as well.
Essentially I would imagine an alternative to those based on e.g. AST representations of types, such as that of `Language.Haskell.Exts`, `ghc-lib-parser`, or others.

Comment: `typeOf $ fn param` does not call `fn`, since `typeOf` does not evaluate its argument. One can even use `typeOf $ fn (undefined :: Bool)`.

Comment: @chi that sounds great, looks like that does what I was hoping for! Would you mind posting this as an answer?

Comment: @KiaraGrouwstra I think you're still missing the point a bit. Please, do go through the exercise. Do imagine potential usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `typeOf` does not evaluate its argument, so your posted code never actually calls `fn`.

More succinctly, one can even use `typeOf $ fn (undefined :: Bool)` to pass a bottom argument to `fn` without triggering an exception.

That being said, I can not understand why you think you need to compute types a runtime. This is very rarely needed in Haskell. What is your actual goal?

Comment: Thanks, accepted!
@chi, @FydorSoikin: My use-case is neural program synthesis; I wanna generate a bunch of functions, turn them into skeletal versions consisting of holes typed as their function signature, randomly generate sample inputs, and get their corresponding outputs to train the neural synthesizer. To randomly generate sample inputs I'm using `Test.QuickCheck.Gen`, tho that only works given a concrete type. So I wanna also randomly generate type instances for type variables, each of which correspond to an output type. So I figured I'd calculate those too. Not sure if useful yet tho!

Comment: @KiaraGrouwstra Calculating a type at runtime won't help you at all. You still won't be able to lookup instances of `Gen` at runtime, because they simply don't exist at runtime. Haskell doesn't have runtime type information like, say, Java or JavaScript or .NET.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yeah, I guess that'd involve like invoking the compiler at run-time using e.g. `hint` library...